# How to find the maximum area of this isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles

I'm trying to solve this question.

> Given that one side of an isosceles triangle is 5, and the radius is 3/2, how to find the maximum value of the area of this triangle?

I'm thinking about separating the case. One is that 5 is one of the equal sides. In the second, 5 can also be the base. However, how can I calculate the area of the triangle given the inradius? I know that there is a formula $K = rS$, where $K$ is the area, $r$ the inradius, $S$ the semi-perimeter. However, I have no idea about how I can use this one here. Any hints and help are appreciated!

Comment: In both cases, you can easily find the sides of the triangle given inradius $ = 1.5$

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Case 1): Suppose $(AC=b)=(AB=c)=5$, We use this formula:

$$r=(p-a)\tan \frac{\alpha}2$$

where p is half perimeter and $\alpha$ is the angle opposite side a.

$$p-a=\frac{a+b+c}2-a=\frac{10-a}2$$

So for $r=\frac 32 $we have:

$\tan \frac{\alpha}2=\frac 3{10-a}$

Construction is possible only if $\alpha=74^o$ which gives:

$a=10-\frac 3{\tan \frac{74}2}=10-4=6$

and area of triangle $S= 15$.

Case 2): $a=5$, $b=c$ then we have:

$(b-\frac 5 2)\tan \frac{\alpha}2=\frac 32\space\space\space\space\space (1)$

$S=\frac{a\times h_a}2$

$h_a= b\cos \frac{\alpha}2$

$S=\frac{5b\cos \frac {\alpha}2}2\space\space\space\space\space (2)$

The system of equations (1) and (2) has only one acceptable solution on which we can construct an isosceles triangle:

$b=c=5.3$ and $\alpha=56.3$ which gives area $S=11.7$.

So area is maximum when $b=c$ for a fixed r.